# HTTP RAW Request not working

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

I am using JMeter 4.0, this time I use HTTP RAW request, but it is not showing the proper response, my actual response message is **success**. I am also using HTTP Cookie manager.

Is it required to put Cookie: JSESSIONID in HTTP RAW request page as Request Data? If yes, then how will I do it? It is showing at **Sample Request** not in **response body**.

**Sampler Result**

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2018-05-15 18:30:14 IST`enter code here
Load time: 20014
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 10
Size in bytes: 2
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 2
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized

Response headers:
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=A1928A9F41209E241F4ABAFB6DC515E9; Path=/bbbp/; HttpOnly
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 15 May 2018 12:54:07 GMT

SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

**Request**

```
POST /bbbp/api/uploadFiles HTTP/1.1
Host: devserver.sdrc.co.in
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 25358

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://devserver.sdrc.co.in:8080
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: Type: application/json
Referer: http://devserver.sdrc.co.in:8080/bbbp/data-entry-awareness
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

**Response data**

```
a2
```

[image]

Comment: From what you posted (Request section) it doesn't look like you are sending any cookies. Please make sure you are using Cookie Manager correctly, and that your login actually succeeds.

Comment: @KirilS. Thanks for your feedback, yes my login succeed, and I have 5 upload request. out of that 4 are HTTP Request and one is HTTP RAW Request. I am facing the problem only at  HTTP RAW Request. Please provide me any reference to it. and please check my above code, I think something mistake was done in my code.

Comment: oh you are using a different sampler... not a raw tab of the standard sampler. Well, that sampler expects you to put cookies in directly in sampler, it won't respect cookie manager.